# regular expression for excluding filename

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

i am trying to upload file with extension like  .pdf or .xls 
i want to exclude .sh .exe , .js or .bat extension from the file name either these are end of the name or in between the file name 
ex. filename.exe.pdf I want it should excluded

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])(?!(exe|sh|js|bat))+(.pdf|.xls)$
```

using above pattern if the filename is file.pdf then  it is acceptable but i want if the filename is filename.exe.pdf   then it should be exclude exe filename

currently with this  pattern its matching till  e.pdf for filename.exe.pdf

Comment: I would test for two matches. The first being the one you want and the second being what you don't want.

Comment: If the filename can include at most two periods try [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wWGKWO/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:](?!\.(?:exe|js|bat|sh)\.))+?(?:\.pdf|\.xls)$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/CdSD86/2) and [graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5Cs_%5C%5C.%5C-%3A%5D(%3F!%5C.(%3F%3Aexe%7Cjs%7Cbat%7Csh)%5C.))%2B%3F(%3F%3A%5C.pdf%7C%5C.xls)%24)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
/^(?!.*(?:\.(?:exe|sh|js|bat)(?:\.|$))).*\.(?:pdf|xls)$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pP2wXo/1/) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F!.*(%3F%3A%5C.(%3F%3Aexe%7Csh%7Cjs%7Cbat)(%3F%3A%5C.%7C%24))).*%5C.(%3F%3Apdf%7Cxls)%24):

[image]

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - string start
- `(?!.*(?:\.(?:exe|sh|js|bat)(?:\.|$)))` - that is not followed with

  - `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\.` - dot
  - `(?:exe|sh|js|bat)` - any of the extensions listed
  - `(?:\.|$)` - a dot or end of string
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.`-  dot
- `(?:pdf|xls)` - `pdf` or `xls`
- `$` - end of string

Comment: i am trying some more  combination now one problem , if the name is like screenshot.pdf or nexe.csv  or  sh ,exe ,bat,js words in filename then it give the error like regular expression does not match,I am using regEx()  in angular to match the pattern.

Comment: @Deep How do you use it in Angular? Using `Validators`? `screenshot.pdf` [matches well](https://regex101.com/r/pP2wXo/2), `nexe.csv` does not as it ends with `csv`.

Comment: I did  not used validators.I am using regRx()  to  match regular expression.  const regex = new RegExp("^(?!.*(?:\.(?:exe|sh|js|bat)(?:\.|$))).*\.(?:pdf|xls|xlsx)$", 'i')  ; 
filename.match(regex)) like this.

Comment: @Deep Same error as most people make. Do not use RegExp constructor if the pattern is static. Use a regex literal, just like in my answer. `const regex = /^(?!.*(?:\.(?:exe|sh|js|bat)(?:\.|$))).*\.(?:pdf|xls)$/i;`. Why didn't you use it? If I had recommended a `RegExp` constructor notation, I would have posted it. But it is not the case here. Did you use Allan's pattern in the constructor, too? It won't work that way either. You need to double backslashes for these patterns to work there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like:

```
 var file = files[0], type = file.type;
 if(type.match(/\.(pdf|xls)$/)){
   // only if .pdf or .xls
 }
```